# python file is incomplete, how to wait till it is complete before handling back to parent process

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I want to be able to set off a subprocess which writes a file to the server and then wait till it is completely finished before handling back to the parent process.
I recieve a image file from a post request. I parse it and I write it to the server with the following code... which is fine.

```
path="/var/bla/bla/bla/"
original_fname = file1['filename']
output_file = open(os.path.join(path,original_fname), 'w')
output_file.write(file1['body'])
```

The problem is I then have to access this file using imagemagick command line tool after it is created to get certain data. But with the above code it is too early and the process is not finished creating the file.
I want to do this after the above code...

```
subprocess.Popen(stdout=output_file)
Popen.communicate()
```

but  getting the following error....

> 'Popen' object has no attribute '_child_created'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you closing the file after you finish writing to it? Try closing the file after you finish writing to it.

Comment: Hi Kevin, No . How would you do that?

Comment: In this instance, `output_file.close()`.

Comment: Ha Ha. Yes. Thats all it is. Put that in an answer,. thank you.  as usual i was trying to complicate things:)

Comment: It should also be `process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=outputfile)` and `process.communicate()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not close the file after writing it. You can do it this way:

```
output_file = open(os.path.join(path,original_fname), 'w')
output_file.write(file1['body'])
output_file.close()
```

But I recommend using the `with` keyword, which takes care of closing the file descriptor even if an error happens in the block:

```
with open(os.path.join(path,original_fname), 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(file1['body'])
```